# Why does tbl_df affect decompose()?

Tags: r, dplyr, forecasting

I have been learning the basic methods of decomposition of a time series. I have been practicing on the datasets available in R.

```
> library(magrittr)
> library(dplyr)
> library(gdata)
> library(fpp2)
> library(seasonal)
> tsdata <- EuStockMarkets[,1]
> decompts <- decompose(tsdata, type = "mult")
> tsdata <- tbl_df(tsdata)
> decompts <- decompose(tsdata, type = "mult")
Error in decompose(tsdata, type = "mult") : 
time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

While running the decompose command directly on tsdata processes it, Why does having the data in the tbl_df format provide an error?

Comment: `tbl_df(EuStockMarkets[,1])` is `tbl_df` that has one col (colname is `x`). But `EuStockMarkets[,1]` is a vector. `decompose(tbl_df(EuStockMarkets[,1])$x)` runs.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much :)